# Set Different Layout for Different Module in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have two module Student and Teacher. 
I also have two different layout one is studentlayout.phtml and another is teacherlayout.phtml

How can I set studentlayout for Student module and teacherlayout for Teachermodule?

As Per Sam's answer .Thanks Its working fine.

but i also want to set two different layout For Teacher.
So i add following code in my main config file for project:

```
'module_layouts' => array(

    'Teacher' => array(
      'default' => 'layout/adminlayout',
      'login'    => 'layout/loginlayout',
    ),
    'Student' => 'layout/studentlayout',
),
```

My module.config.php file for teacher module:

```
    'module_layouts' => array(

    'Teacher' => array(
      'default' => 'layout/adminlayout',
      'login'    => 'layout/loginlayout',
    ),
      'Student' => 'layout/studentlayout',
 ),
```

But all time all action of Teacher module take adminlayout. why login action can't take loginlayout?its ovveride?

Comment: I have reffered all old post here, but its cant give me proper answer so i post my question here.

Comment: I use EdpModuleLayouts but which is used only for set layout in same module. How its call for multiple module?

Comment: EdpModuleLayouts is SPECIFICALLY designed to work with several layouts for several different Modules. I **strongly** suggest you read the readme about the module to understand how it works (or to simply look at Module.php and understand the code - it's really straight forward code)

Answer (score 3):

**Usage**

Using EdpModuleLayouts is very, very simple. In any module config or autoloaded config file simply specify the following:

```
array(
    'module_layouts' => array(
        'Teacher' => 'layout/teacher',
        'Student' => 'layout/student'
    ),
);
```

That's it! Of course you need to define those layouts, too... just check Application Modules `module.config.php` to see how to define a layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change layout for your one action you can use layout() plugin in your controllers action, or if you want different layout for all actions in one controller only in your module you can do it in bootstrap:

```
public function onBootstrap(\Zend\EventManager\EventInterface $e) {
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEventManager->attach('Auth\Controller\AuthController', \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'onDispatch'));
}

public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e) {
    $controller = $e->getTarget();      
    $controller->layout('layout/loginLayout');
}
```

After each action in that controller you will change root ViewModel layout you can go further and specify here more controllers where you want your layout like this

```
$sharedEventManager>attach(array('Auth\Controller\AuthController',
'Auth\Controller\Registration'),
\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'onDispatch'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple trick. I am surprised that Zend Framework 2 does not have proper layout handler for different modules... that should be like basic thing